# Why does switching to Kotlin break Android Studio code assist

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When developing in the Java programming language within Android Studio
there are a number of time saving shortcuts such as typing

```
logt<TAB>
logd<TAB>
logm<TAB>
```

that add Log Cat statements

Why do these not work when developing with Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these Live Templates are set as applicable in Java. Also, they are written following the Java syntax.
If you want you can add new live templates for Kotlin.

[image]

Comment: why werent these provided "Out Of The Box" for Kotlin?

Comment: I think you should ask the Android Studio Team :D

Answer (score 1):

You can get a config file and follow the instructions from this.
[A Medium post for Live Templates for Kotlin Log statements in Android Studio](https://medium.com/@dumazy/live-templates-for-kotlin-log-statements-in-android-studio-f8b64670e572)